# allow redirects with iptables

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, iptables

with the following rules, php can't make a `redirect` to another file. it's freezes at the point when it gets to`header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
                header("Location:" . $VIDEO);`
 or could be `get_headers();` on my php script.

my iptables:

```
 iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:22151 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:webcache 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:http 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

what i've tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

as soon as i remove the `DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere` everything works fine.

Comment: None of your rules filter based on the content of the HTTP traffic, so I don't think the problem is what you think it is.

Comment: Not that it matters, but you don't need to send a `Content-type` header when you're redirecting. The client ignores the content you send, and goes to the page in the `Location` header instead. Are you saying that these iptables rules prevent the client from receiving the `Location` header?

Comment: @Barmar yes. or could be it stops at `get_headers();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `get_headers()`, your script makes an outgoing HTTP connection. You need to allow the reply traffic back in, by allowing *established* sessions.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Allowing_Established_Sessions) for more info